# Issue with filenames with .php in the name image.php.jpg

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

Just moved a site from a Windows server running IIS to a Linux server running Apache, there are some images titled, for example, image.php.jpg (they are images).

When accessing them, I get this error:

```
A file permissions error has occurred. Please check the permissions on the script and the directory it is in and try again.
```

From reading a little, I need to put something in the .htaccess file, of which there isn't one as it was a site on a Windows server.

Could someone please kindly indicate what I need to put in the .htaccess file to avoid the server processing 'anything' with .php in the filename as a .php page?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: An example for why it's a bad idea to put dots in a filename if they not indicate the file extension.

Comment: @wumm — No, it isn't.

Comment: `.htaccess` is an Apache thing, not a UNIX thing, you can use them on Windows servers.

Comment: @Quentin, thank you I have edited the post to correctly indicate the server and webserver it is running.

Comment: Apache shouldn't be processing this file as a PHP script as it ends with .jpg not .php, are you sure this is the problem? Can you verify that the apache user can read these image files?

Comment: @mTorres, the permission is 644 and if I take the .php part out of the filename, it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

The folder and the image files need to have "read" permissions for the apache user.

If you have access to a shell on the operational system, try these:

```
chmod 755 <folder name>
```

This will give permissions to all system users to browse the folder and for yourself to change-it.
And inside the folder:

```
chmod 644 *
```

this will give permission to all users to read the files and for you to change-it.

If you don't have access to the system shell, try to give those same permissions using an FTP client...

Comment: Hi Sergio, I can confirm that the folders are 755 and the individual files are 644, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<FilesMatch \.jpg$>
SetHandler image/jpg
</FilesMatch>
```